# Recharts nested data from dynamic line components

Tags: reactjs, recharts

is it possible for Recharts library to have nested keys.

```
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Sat Jan 1',
    curr: 4000,
    prev: 2400,
  },
  {
    name: 'Sun Jan 2',
    curr: 3000,
    prev: 1398,
  },
];
```

```
const data2 = [
  {
    name: 'Sat Jan 1',
    lines: [
      {
        curr: 4000,
        prev: 2400,
      },
      {
        curr: 5000,
        prev: 6400,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Sun Jan 2',
    lines: [
      {
        curr: 2700,
        prev: 1398,
      },
      {
        curr: 6000,
        prev: 1438,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I want to have nesting for multiple object that i will get from api with same key names. Is it possible to render `<Line />` component dynamically with this structure ? Or is there any other way if i want to render unlimited number of lines. I pass data to `<LineChart data={data} />` and use dataKey with `curr` and `prev` names now.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

[image]

This is an example in the recharts docs

[Example](https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/LineChartHasMultiSeries)